# Transforming 240 VAC to 5V/gnd

Tags: ac, signal, rectifier

My 240 VAC relay can be either on or off. I'd like to transform that to 1/0 signal for an input pin on my Arduino. I may be able to build something with a rectifier, a step-down and a couple of transistors, but probably not.

Surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: Why not a current transformer?

Comment: Simple solution:  attach standard usb cell phone charger to relay output.  Attach charger's output to arduino.  All the high voltage stuff is taken care of my that cheap tested and certified adapter.  Make sure it actually puts out 5v under no load.  Some cheap ones don't.

Comment: A mains-neon and a photo-transistor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an opto isolator and remember that isolating the AC mains from your Arduino is probably a good idea. There are plenty of opto's around that are easily interfaced to a mains AC supply as switched by your relay. "Encase" the opto-diode within a bridge rectifier circuit and connect the AC terminals of the bridge (via a capacitor and series resistor) to the AC.

The output of the opto is typically a transistor that will need a pull-up resistor to Vcc, maybe 10k ohm. Here's an opto that should work: -

[image]

Comment: The opto you mention already incorporates a bridge rectifier - it might be good to clarify this, as the answer currently seems to imply that a separate bridge rectifier is required.

Comment: @anindo you've just done that for me LOL